# Zero-One Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Update: it times out at numbers >44 that are input. Any ideas on how to stop it timing out?
My code is supposed to output the smallest number that contains only 1s or 0s that the input divides into. In this example, 34's smallest multiple that contains only 1s or 0s is 111010. However, my code only outputs an infinite loop...Any ideas?

```
#example input: 34
#example ouput: 111010
#2<n<1000
print("Please enter your number...")
n = int(input())
counter = 0

mylist = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

t = n
check = str(t)
while any(x in check for x in mylist):
    counter += 1
    t = n * counter
    continue
else:
    print(t)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be an infinite loop? Neither `x` nor `check` nor `list` is updated inside the loop, so your `any(...)` condition always evaluates to the same value.

Comment: You're testing `check` and updating `t`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey oh...sorry, i'm a newbie to coding! any suggestions to fix it? :)

Comment: @valkiyare -modify the values that you test so the loop ends ...

Comment: We can of course fix the code for you, but it would be good to know if this was just a simple oversight or if you honestly expected the loop to end. Because if you did, we have a lot to explain...

Comment: @Aran-Fey I think I just missed out the fact I should have been updating...thank you for the help everyone though :)

Comment: @YannVernier thank you! all fixed

Comment: @Aran-Fey it times out for numbers bigger than 34 unfortunately..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the given number to a sum until it's string only contains 0 and 1:

```
# you already solved the input part, so skipping it here
n = 34
summed = n
allowed = {"0","1"}
while set(str(summed)) - allowed:   #  @MadPhysicists suggestion instead of 
                                          #  any(x not in allowed for x in str(summed)):
    summed += n
else:
    print(summed)
```

Output:

```
111010
```

No idea, but my guess would be that adding is faster then multiplying in the long run.

Comment: A better way to check the digits might be `while set(str(summed)) - allowed:`

Comment: thanks - my code times out for numbers >~34 though :(

Comment: @Valkiyare what do you mean by "times out for > 34" ?